# Add a custom control to the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

Good day!

Have a user control:

[image]

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class LinkLabelList
    Private Sub LinkLabelList_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabelList_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
        Me.BackColor = Color.Silver
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabelList_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
        Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseLeave
        Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseEnter
        Me.BackColor = Color.Silver
    End Sub

    Private _UserMail As String
    Private _icon As Image

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property UserMail() As String
        Get
            Return _UserMail
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserMail = value
            LinkLabel1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Icon() As Image
        Get
            Return _icon
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Image)
            _icon = value
            PictureBox1.Image = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and the form itself:

[image]

enter the data in the text field and add the button to the FlowLayoutPanel1

```vb
 Dim lll As New LinkLabelList
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        lll.UserMail = TextBox1.Text
        lll.Icon = My.Resources.user16x
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lll)
    End Sub
```

The problem is that only one UserControl is added. How can I add a new UserControl on a button each time? For example, the first e-mail was added by pressing the button, the text field is cleared, enter another e-mail and add it to the existing one.
each time you add, the already existing UserControl will be lost

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is your code, fix it like below

```
  ' Dim lll As New LinkLabelList  <- delete
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim lll As New LinkLabelList '<- add
        lll.UserMail = TextBox1.Text
        lll.Icon = My.Resources.user16x
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lll)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Works. I didn't think of it myself.
One more question, of course not on this topic, but suddenly you can help. How can X remove a User Control from a FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: What control is the 'X'?
First, create an event for 'X'.
Then you need to remove the LinkLabelList using FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove() .

Comment: @Think2826 You mean `Me.Dispose()`